# Run function when error occurs without try

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling

I am trying to run a function whenever an error occurs. I don't want to use `try` or `except` because my code is very large and there are so much chances of an error to occur , so I can't use `try`.. everywhere. This is what I am expecting:

```
>>> if ValueError:  #don't works , just assuming.
    print("Hey! You are done.")

>>> int("abc")
Hey! You are done.
>>> int("1b")
Hey! You are done.
>>>
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Couldn't you wrap the whole code block in which the error may occur in a try/except?  Also, could you give us some context to your program to see if any other things will be able to be done to check if an exception will occur

Comment: @NChauhan I have to set such multiple statements for each error.

Comment: Is there a way you could use more 'reliable' input data? Or pre-filter values that will raise an error

Answer (score 2):

If your code is a whole block, I recommend splitting it into functions. From here, you can wrap each function in a decorator that takes an error and a function to be run on error:

```
def handle_error(error, error_func):
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            r = None
            try:
                r = func(*args, **kwargs)
            except error as e:
                r = error_func()
            finally:
                return r
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Then use on functions like so:

```
def bad_value():
    print('bad value given!')

@handle_error(ValueError, bad_value)
def multiply(a, b):
    return a * b
```

Of course, you can be more 'broad', and catch all exceptions...

```
@handle_error(Exception, error_func)
def func(): 
    # ...
```

Comment: I try using it like `multiply("df","f")` but it raised error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'r' referenced before assignment`.

Comment: @hani try adding a `r = None` above the try/except code. Which line did the error occur on?

Comment: I See, it looks like the function raised TypeError instead of ValueError: go ahead and change that to `@handle_error(TypeError, bad_value)`

Answer (score 0):

A ValueError is triggered by a particular piece of code, and will raise itself immediately after the offending statement. `int("abc")` will raise a ValueError on its own, and the program execution will stop, before it reaches any `if ValueError` statement.

You need a `try`/`except` block to allow python to catch the error and continue executing. I can't see any way to achieve what you want without one.

Comment: The OP uses this 'restriction' of no `try/except` blocks as they say there will be too many occurrences of this possibility

Comment: I agree, but there must be a try/except block somewhere, as you have included in the example code in your answer.